# Avoid layout element to move the second element out of the layout when is too big

Tags: android, layout

I have two `TextViews` in the same row, next to each other. The first TextView may be so big that can be bigger than the width of the screen. So when this happens I need the second one to be visible and have the first one with `ellipsize = true` and show the 3 dots. The second one has more or less the same size always, and it should be always visible.

This is what I have now:

```
<RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/horizontalItemTitle"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/horizontalItemDescriptionSecond"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">
        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/horizontalItemDescription2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/spacing_x_small"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:textColor="@color/item_subtitle"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_caption"
                tools:text="10 songs"
                style="@style/AppTheme.Text.Body_2" />
        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/horizontalItemDescriptionSecond2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/spacing_x_small"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/horizontalItemDescription2"
                android:textColor="@color/item_subtitle"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_caption"
                android:visibility="gone"
                android:gravity="start"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                tools:text=", 45 min"
                tools:visibility="visible"
                style="@style/AppTheme.Text.Body_2" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

I also tried with ConstraintLayout and LinearLayout but I couldn't make it work as I want.

**EDIT**

Here 2 images of how it have to be. Please focus on the last line

1.- When the first textview is small.

[image]

the second text view is just next to the first one.

2.- When the first textview is large.

[image]

The first text view end with ... but doesn't move the second text view out of the layout.

Comment: do you want both textView visible

Comment: just set android:maxWidth="100dp" or some harcodded value to first TextView to show 3 dots at the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this behaviour working with the constraint layout:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:background="@color/red"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            android:id="@+id/test1"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/test2"
            android:background="@color/green"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:text="10 songs"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed" />

    <TextView
            android:background="@color/primaryLight"
            android:id="@+id/test2"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/test1"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=", 45 min" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 3):

I have updated the layout. Try with this layout

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="1"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/horizontalItemTitle"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/horizontalItemDescriptionSecond"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/horizontalItemDescription2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.7"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/spacing_x_small"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:textColor="@color/item_subtitle"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_caption"
        tools:text="10 songs"
        style="@style/AppTheme.Text.Body_2" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/horizontalItemDescriptionSecond2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.3"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/spacing_x_small"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:textColor="@color/item_subtitle"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_caption"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:gravity="start"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        tools:text=", 45 min"
        tools:visibility="visible"
        style="@style/AppTheme.Text.Body_2" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: With this the second text view is always stack in the right side of the layout and it should be always next to the first. I just edit the question with images so you can see what I need.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by using `android:layout_weight` attribute and by setting `android:maxWidth` according to big text.

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:orientation="horizontal">
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/horizontalItemDescription2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:maxWidth="100dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/spacing_x_small"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:textColor="@color/item_subtitle"
    android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_caption"
    tools:text="10 songs"
    style="@style/AppTheme.Text.Body_2" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/horizontalItemDescriptionSecond2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/spacing_x_small"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:textColor="@color/item_subtitle"
    android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_caption"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:gravity="start"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
    tools:text=", 45 min"
    tools:visibility="visible"
    style="@style/AppTheme.Text.Body_2" />
```

Comment: With this approach I get a fix size for the first text view and it should change depending the size of the text but avoid to be big enough to move the second one out of the layout.

Comment: @IbanArriola set `android:maxWidth` to big text..whenever text will b bigger then size will vary untill maximum size and then 3 dots will be appear...see my edited answer

Answer (score 0):

You can add a property **maxWidth** and provide the equal max width in both TextViews like this.

```
<TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:maxWidth="@dimen/_100sdp"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                 />
<TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:maxWidth="@dimen/_100sdp"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                 />
```